# How to configure an autoplay of music when plug in earbuds in a pc/laptop?

Tags: windows, media-player, background-process, vlc, audio-player

Just like on android I would like to be able to auto launch my music player, in this case playing music already, every time I plug the earbuds.

I know I can create a shortcut for it using the command line structure for example to open my default music folder:

```
vlc.exe "[path to folder]"
```

in this case something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "G:\Musics"
```

just like this:

[image]

What is missing to me is a way to detect the event of plugging the earbud connector. I know it is possible since the bundle software of my sound card installed an background application that alerts with a baloon message in the notification bar when the phones are plugged in.

I know That it will require some kind of service/application running in the background all the time. Does anyone have an idea of how to do it?